# JSON objects not getting saved to my Database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

So I have an interface that allows users to add songs from their computer to a list. I'm trying to save the name of the song and possibly more to the database but it all that happens when I click save is it adds an id and null for name and link (I'm not worried about link right now).

**Code For Adding files to the list**

```
this.state = {
      files: [],
    };


const readFile = (file) => {

    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject({ error })
      }

      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        resolve({
          name: file.name.replace( /_|\.mp3/gi, " "),
          link: e.target.result

        })
      }

      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    })
  }

  const allReaders = Array.from(event.target.files).map(readFile)

   Promise.all(allReaders)
    .then(fileList => {
      console.log(fileList)
        this.setState({ files: fileList });
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.error(error)
    });

}
```

**Code To Save To The Database**

```
save(event) {
  let that = this;
  let files = that.state.files;
  event.preventDefault();

 let data = files.map(({ name }) => ({ name, id: Math.random().toFixed(3) }))

  let request = new Request('http://localhost:3000/songs', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });

console.log(data);

  fetch(request)
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.ok) {
        return response.json();
        console.log("respose ok")
      } else {
        throw new Error("BAD HTTP stuff");
      }
    })
          .then((data) => {
            console.log("Data" + data)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error " + error);
          });

}
```

**Here's my post request on my node app**

```
**queries.js**

const addSong = (request, response) => {
  const { name, link } = request.body

  pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (name, link) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *', [name, link], (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log(results.rows);
  }

  response.status(201).send(`Song added`)
})

}

**index.js**
const app = express();
const db = require('./queries');
app.post('/songs', db.addSong)
```

Answer (score 0):

One error I see is in queries.js
You should send the response in the else (when no error came from the database)
Something like that

```
**queries.js**

const addSong = (request, response) => {
  const { name, link } = request.body

  pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (name, link) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *', [name, link], (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error
    console.log(error)
    response.status(403).send(`Error adding song`)
  } else {
    console.log(results.rows);
    response.status(201).send(`Song added`)
  }


})

}

**index.js**
const app = express();
const db = require('./queries');
app.post('/songs', db.addSong)
```

Can you post more details about your issue? Is it a backend or frontend problem ?

Comment: It's both because when I save the object to the database it displays null for name and link and doesn't save to the list on the frontend. When I console.log data from let = data it displays the array with the correct info.